# OutOfMemoryException when loading large string from Xml file

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to simply load a very large string from an Xml file and save it to a temporary file inside the `IXmlSerializable#ReadXml` method, the code being used is below.

The problem is I'm getting an `OutOfMemoryException` on the `reader.ReadStartElement("data");` line.  It appears that the `XmlReader` is attempting to preload the value string and as it is ~500Mb in this case it is failing to allocate a `StringBuilder` for it.

Is there some better way of copying this string into a file, or some way to bypass the preloading of the `XmlReader`?

```
public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
{
    // Read other elements

    reader.ReadStartElement("data");

    this.dataFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
    FileStream tempFile = File.Create(this.dataFile);

    char[] buffer = new char[CHUNK_SIZE];
    int count;

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(tempFile))
    {
        while ((count = reader.ReadValueChunk(buffer, 0, CHUNK_SIZE)) != 0)
        {
            writer.Write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
    }
    reader.ReadEndElement();
}
```

Comment: Ouch; that is... tricky. I assume it is far to late to suggest that maybe xml isn't the right format for a 500Mb enclosure?

Comment: I would not use xml and were ever you are parsing it give it a filestream so it is not reading the entire string at once. Because as a unicode string you are already doubling the size (if it is stored as ascii).

Comment: Normally it is nowhere near 500Mb, this is just part of the stress testing.  It _can_ be 500Mb (or even bigger) though so it needs to support this.

Nowhere is this supposed to be getting stored as a string, it was originally but once I realised how big it could get I changed to this chunking and streaming for both reading and writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution, the problem isn't in the `IXmlSerializable#ReadXml` method, it's actually in the method that calls `XmlSerializer#Deserialize`.  Originally I had this:

```
private void OpenSavedData(StreamReader strmReader, string fileName)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SavedData));
    SavedData savedData = serializer.Deserialize(strmReader) as SavedData;

    // Process data
}
```

By default `Deserialize` generates a `XmlTextReader` to pass to the `ReadXml` method.  If I had actually made it past the `ReadStartElement` call I would have found that `XmlTextReader` doesn't support `GetValueChunk`.

Instead I need to instantiate an `XmlReader` myself using the `XmlReader.Create` method.  This will create an implementation that doesn't preload the values and supports chunking.

```
private void OpenSavedData(StreamReader strmReader, string fileName)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SavedData));

    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.CloseInput = true;
    settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;

    SavedData savedData = null;

    using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(strmReader, settings))
    {
        savedData = serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader) as SavedData;
    }

    // Process data
}
```

This then allows the `ReadXml` call to succeed.